# Is there a way to adjust the Nishita sky horizon location?

Tags: texturing, shaders

I'm wondering if there is a way to keep the horizon lined up with the ground while having a higher and more oblique camera angle, and without having to extent the ground plane excessively.  I was thinking there might be a way to input coordinates so the texture could be moved up or down but have not been unable to figure out how.  Any thoughts would be appreciated even if just to confirm it's not possible. Thanks

Comment: Umm… Try [Texture Coordinate - Generated]—[Mapping]—[Sky Texture]

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking something like that might work except the sky texture has no inputs.